# MKAnnotation viewForAnnotation never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have already add `UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>`  in .h and already add

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad {
     self.mapView.delegate = self;
 }
```

but the method viewForAnnotation never called

MapViewController.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

   @interface Tela1ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {
       IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
   }

   @property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;
   @end
```

MapViewController.m

```
  -(void) viewDidLoad {
      self.mapView.delegate = self;
  }

  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
      AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication shared

      mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
      mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;

      CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: appDelegate.latitude, longitude: appDelegate.longitude};
      MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta:0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2};
      MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

      [mapView setRegion:region];

      PlaceMark *addAnnotation = [[PlaceMark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];  
      [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];  
      [self.view addSubview:mapView];
  }

  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
      NSLog(@"test");
  }
```

Comment: Verify that your mapView outlet is connected properly in InterfaceBuilder.  If it is, post your actual @interface line, and also post your mapView:viewForAnnotation: method.

Comment: BTW you must call `[super viewDidAppear:animated` at some point in your `viewDidAppear:` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, couple of things to fix in your code ...

**Delegate of MKMapView**

Is `nil`. Why? Because you set delegate of `MKMapView` in `viewDidLoad` method. But when you look at `viewDidAppear:`, you're allocating new `MKMapView` and you're not setting delegate there. And because `viewDidLoad` is called before `viewDidAppear:`, delegate is simply `nil` = not set.

**Calling super**

When you override some methods, read documentation. Because you can find this in `viewDidAppear:` documentation for example:

*You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with presenting the view. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.*

**MKMapView & IBOutlet**

And also don't understand why do you have `MKMapView` as `IBOutlet` and then you're allocating new `MKMapView` and adding it as subview. Also if your `IBOutlet` is really connected to a `MKMapView` in your XIB, you'll end up with two `MKMapView`s, because the old one (from XIB) is not removed from superview.

You're clearly messing things up. Go and read more about UIKit, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the last several lines of you viewDidAppear method with the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  location.latitude, .longitude =  location.longitude};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta = 0.2, .longitudeDelta =  0.2};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

[mapView setRegion:region];

MapAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```